# Looping Question - Repeat code many times but replace a column reference for each iteration

Tags: sql-server

I am very new to SQL Server and am looking for somebody to talk to me like I'm in kindergarten.

I want to repeat this code, but I want to replace 'Coverage Category' with different terms like 'Race', 'County', etc (these terms align with some column names from the data source).

What is the simplest way to repeat this code and replace the column reference?

```
select
**'Coverage Category'** as 'Data Type' 
 ,**[Coverage Category]** as 'Values'
 ,'Calendar Year' as [Year Type] 
 ,'Annual' as [Aggregation Level]
,[Calendar Year]
into #temp_annual_1 /*is there a way to add 'Coverage Category' into the output name? */
from [Report].[tablename]
group by **[Coverage Category]**,[Calendar Year] 
order by [Calendar Year]
```

Comment: I feel like this is an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). Looping is one of the *last* things you want to to in SQL; it's a set based language so you should be using a set based methods.  Are you saying you want to run multiple queries, but changing the column each time? Why?

Comment: SQL itself doesn't let you use "dynamic" column references. Is this intended as a one-time thing? Are you mostly trying to save typing?

Comment: There is no aggregation in your query so group by will throw a syntax errors. As to the simplest way research dynamic sql